# Add handler for contextmenustrip in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to convert this to Powershell but I'm not quite sure how to. The important part is creating a handler for the trayMenu item.

```
NotifyIcon trayIcon;
ContextMenuStrip trayMenu;
trayMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
trayMenu.Items.Add("Login", ContextMenuStripItemImages).Click += new EventHandler(Login_Click); //Create a new item in the context menu strip and link its Click event with Login_Click
trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
trayIcon.ContextMenuStrip = trayMenu; //Set the ContextMenuStrip of trayIcon to trayMenu
}

private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something when Login is clicked
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
trayMenu.Items.Add("Login", ContextMenuStripItemImages).add_Click({... script here ...})
```

Sender is represented with `$this` and e (EventArgs) by `$_`.